# Dynamically set the VALUE of an text-INPUT element to default by clicking SELECT option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, here is the first thing that what I want to do:

**1)** Lets say a user has been adding text to one or to both of the input fields. Now, if the user is either selecting *option value 'Name1'* or *option value 'Name2*' of the select field the input fields value have to be reseted. How can this be done?

```
<div id='CustomerIsNotInDatabase'>
    <input id='vlastname' name='ulastname' type='text' value=''></input>
    <input id='vfirstname' name='ufirstname' type='text' value=''></input>
</div>

<div id='customerIsInDatabase'>
<select>
    <option selected='true' value=''>Choose</option>
    <option value='Name1'></option>
    <option value='Name2'></option>
</select>
</div>
```

**2)** Now the other way round: If either option value 'Name1' or option value 'Name2' is selected: How can this value be reseted to the 1st option with value '' if the user adds text to an input field?

Comment: Do set a text input element value, just do `elem.value = '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** For the first question.

> If the user is either selecting option value 'Name1' or option value 'Name2' of the select field the input fields value have to be reseted

You can use `change` event to handle the user change and reset input using `val('')` :

```
$('#customerIsInDatabase select').change(function(){
     if ( $(this).val() != '' )
     {
         $('#vlastname').val('');
         $('#vfirstname').val('');
     }
});
```

**2.** For the second question.

> If either option value 'Name1' or option value 'Name2' is selected: How can this value be reseted to the 1st option with value '' if the user adds text to an input field?

You can use `keyup` event to detect user action when any key presed in `input` field :

```
$('#CustomerIsNotInDatabase input').keyup(function()
{
      $('#customerIsInDatabase select').val('').change();
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Full Example :**

```js
$('#customerIsInDatabase select').change(function()
{
     if ( $(this).val() != '' )
     {
         $('#vlastname').val('');
         $('#vfirstname').val('');
     }
});


$('#CustomerIsNotInDatabase input').keyup(function()
{
      $('#customerIsInDatabase select').val('').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='CustomerIsNotInDatabase'>
    <input id='vlastname' name='ulastname' type='text' value=''></input>
    <input id='vfirstname' name='ufirstname' type='text' value=''></input>
</div>

<div id='customerIsInDatabase'>
<select>
    <option selected='true' value=''>Choose</option>
    <option value='Name1'>Name1</option>
    <option value='Name2'>Name2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#customerIsInDatabase select').on('change', function(){
    $('#CustomerIsNotInDatabase').find('input:text').val('');
});

$('#CustomerIsNotInDatabase input').on('keypress', function(){
    $('#customerIsInDatabase select').val('');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aqgb30g/)

**EDIT** (solution based on comment to update the 'selected' attribute)

```
$('#customerIsInDatabase select').on('change', function(){
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    setSelected(selectedVal);   
    $('#CustomerIsNotInDatabase').find('input:text').val('');
});

$('#CustomerIsNotInDatabase input').on('keypress', function(){
    $('#customerIsInDatabase select').val('');
    setSelected('');
});

function setSelected(selVal) {
    $("select option").attr("selected",false);
    $("select option[value='" + selVal +"']").attr("selected",true);
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aqgb30g/1/)

Comment: Nice answer, but If the option choose is selected?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I'm not doing any check on choose as it could only be selected when the selection is being switched from Name1 or Name2 (with OP's requirements when text is typed it will go to choose & when anything other than choose is selected the text will be cleared. when the option is on choose you won't be able to select choose again; the change event won't trigger when trying to switch to the same selected option. This means there won't be an instance where you may run into a situation where the text will be cleared when choose option is selected by the user). Try the fiddle.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki  edited answer so that the 'selected' attribute will be on the correct option (though this is out of scope for OP's question)